# Zebra Label Printer TLP 2824 Plus Prints 2 Labels and Quits

Tags: hardware, printers, zebra-printers

We have the Zebra TLP 2824-Z Plus label printer (ZLP). We recently purchased it, installed the driver and software successfully, and calibrated successfully (held button down at solid green, got single blink then double blink, and then released the button). We went to Zebra and retrieved the updated drivers (certified) and installed them (fyi have tried with and without these drivers - will do nothing without them).

The system it is installed on via USB is a Windows XP Pro 32-bit SP3.

Immediately after configuration, it will do a test print, and let us send the command to feed a label. If we try to print configuration or anything else, to include printing actual labels, it prints two labels/pages, stops, and then blinks red. If we lift the top off and put it down, it blinks green until we press the button. At that time, it will feed about 2 to 3 inches of labels and then print one label. The process repeats indefinitely until we uninstall the printer.

No, clearing the documents will not stop it. A hard reset will not stop it. The only way to get it to do anything else is to uninstall it and start all over again.

How do we fix this issue so we can get a configuration or just print our labels? Or, better yet, what are we doing wrong and how do we do it right? Our last printer worked fine with the exception that they stopped making the labels we used with that printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive sends down an initialization sequence for the printer based on the settings in the Printer Preferences. If, for example, your Printer preferences say that the printer is Thermal mode instead of direct thermal, the driver will send down the command to set the printer to Thermal mode (Ribbon). If your printer is printing Direct Thermal, and has no ribbon physically installed, the printer will think it is in an error mode with no ribbon. This could cause the issue you are seeing.

Ensure that your Printer Preferences are accurate to your printer's configuration, or disable the initialization sequence in the driver

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Indeed we had the setting on Thermal Transfer an dit needed to be on Thermal Direct.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Just make sure all the settings are correct.